# playground results area cant be expanded in xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode9beta6

I have a problem in Xcode Version 9.0 beta 6 .The right side of the playground can't be expanded (view results area) !

I uploaded a video for explanation here :

[xcode 9 beta 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vfqf7ZoQzGg&feature=youtu.be)

any solution ?